# OneToOne relation and NestedSerializer issue about User model

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to do a login app including registration, authentication etc...
I'm getting this error:

`AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field 'user' on serializer 'PictureUserSerializer'.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the 'User' instance.
Original exception text was: 'User' object has no attribute 'user'.`

But, when I check my admin page. The user has been registered with the right informations. I'm not feeling like this error come from nowhere and I must do something wrong. Here is my code:

**logginapp/models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class PictureUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User) #OneToOne link to the Django's User Model               
    avatar = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="avatars/")

    def username(self, user):
        return user.username

    def password(self, user):
        return user.password

    def email(self, user):
        return user.email
```

**loginapp/serializer.py**

```
from django.core.validators import validate_email
from django import forms
from rest_framework import serializers
from loginapp.models import PictureUser

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'email')
        write_only_fields = ('password',)


class PictureUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """                                                                                       
    Serializer to put the PictureUser model into JSON                                         
    """
    user = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = PictureUser
        fields = ('user', 'avatar')
        read_only_fields = ('created',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print (validated_data)
        return User.objects.create_user(validated_data['user']['username'], validated_data['user']['email'],
            validated_data['user']['password']
    )
```

**loginapp/view.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import generics
from .serializer import PictureUserSerializer
from .models import PictureUser

class PictureUserCreateView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    """                                                                                       
    This class define the Create behaviour of a PictureUser                                   
    """
    queryset = PictureUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PictureUserSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to create user from `PictureUserSerializer`, then,

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
    user = User.objects.create_user(**user_data)
    return PictureUser.objects.create(user = user, **validated_data)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`PictureUserSerializer create method` needs to return a `PictureUser` instance, not a `User` instance.